# Composer, Windows Server and the infamous "SSL operation failed with code 1" error

Tags: php, openssl, composer-php, windows-server

I am currently facing a problem with *Composer* and, as I can understand it, *OpenSSL*. I spent the last couple of days trying various solutions that I found over the Web, but without any success.

To go straight to the point, when I try to get some packages with *Composer*, sometimes the following error is thrown:

```
... file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
```

What I read in other *Stack Overflow* posts is this problem is related to a certificate issue. Like it was suggested, I downloaded some certificates (*https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt* and  *https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem*) and edited the values `curl.cainfo` and `openssl.cafile` in my *php.ini* file. Unfortunately, it did not work.

I checked environment variables and I don't have something like `SSL_CERT_FILE` or `SSL_CERT_DIR`. I tried to create them and assign a value to them without more success.

My system is a *Windows Server 2019* and I installed *PHP* myself, but I also tried with a *Wamp* installation. The *DLL* for *CURL* and *OpenSSL* are here and the extensions are enabled in the *php.ini* files. I also encountered this error when I installed *Composer*, so I installed it manually.

I don't know where to look anymore. Does anybody have a suggestion?

Many thanks in advance.

Best regards,

**SOLUTION**

The solution was indeed simple: in our organization, we have our own root and intermediate certificate. I merged both of them with the *pem* file from  *https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem*, set the *php.ini* file accordingly, and it solved the problem.

Comment: You should post solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed simple: in our organization, we have our own root and intermediate certificate. I merged both of them with the pem file from https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem, set the php.ini file accordingly, and it solved the problem.

Comment: Hi @Lancelot how do you get the those certificates in Windows Server?

Comment: Hi @Enrique! On Windows, I extracted the required certifacte with the tool Certificate Manager Tool (certmgr.msc).